# change redirect in controller in case of error Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have created two form to different group customers but when i make error when filling the new form added the error is shown in the first form `customer/account/create`  so how to correct the redirection if i am in the second form.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more details like code and files, then it will be easier for everyone to understand problem better.

Comment: i just overrided the controller creatPostAction

Comment: and duplicated the register.phtml with some new attributes but i still getting errors in the fisrt form not the form i created